# JPA Mapping of Project Entity with Employee Entity

Tags: hibernate, jpa, jpa-2.0

I would like to know how can I map the following requirements using JPA

I have a **Project** Entity with following attributes

```
projectNo (auto generated)
projectRequestedBy
approvedBy
```

**Employee** Entity

```
employeeNumber (primary key)
employeeName
employeeTitle
employeePhone
```

I would like to know how can I efficiently map the `employeeNumber` with projectRequestedBy and approvedBy attributes in Project Entity?

And I would also would like to know how it is possible to display `employeeName`, `employeeTitle` and `employeePhone` attributes when I execute query against `Project` Entity class? Ideally I would want to have the following record if I would try to fetch project record

```
projectNo projectRequestedByName projectRequestedByTitle  approvedByName approvedByTitle
```

Any help is highly appreciable.

**Update 1**

**Project** Entity

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "PROJECT")
public class Project

private Long projectNo;

@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name="EMP_NUMBER", insertable =false, updatable=false)
private Employees employees;
```

**Employees** Entity

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "EMPLOYEES")
public class Employees {
@OneToMany  
@JoinColumn(name="EMP_NUMBER", nullable = false)
private Collection<Project> project;
```

Comment: Read [the documentation](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/4.2/devguide/en-US/html_single/), then try something. If you're stuck, come back here, show what you tried, and explained what didn't work. You want to learn about ManyToOne/OneToMany associations, and about HQL and joins.

Comment: @JBNizet I have updated my question with my entity mapping. I am not very sure about joining the entities to obtain lookup information from `Employees` class. Besides I would want to know join is a best practice in JPA?

Comment: @JBNizet What I meant of `join` best practice is the usage of `@NamedQueries`

Comment: NamedQueries is just a way to change your query place from your code to your entity. then you can get it latter using `session.getNamedQuery("queryName")` so its doesn't realy have relation with a join

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK. First of all, your mapping is wrong. In a bidirectional OneToMany association, the one side must be the inverse side, and this is materialized by the `mappedBy` attribute. Just as shown [in the documentation](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.6/reference/en-US/html_single/#collections-bidirectional)

You have actually two OneToMany/ManyToOne betwen employee and project. An employee requests many projects. An an employee approves many projects.

So the mapping should look like

```
@Entity
public class Employee
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "requester")
    private Set<Project> requestedProjects;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "approver")
    private Set<Project> approvedProjects;
}

@Entity
public class Project
    @ManyToOne
    private Employee requester;

    @ManyToOne
    private Employee approver;
}
```

To get a project with its requester and its approver in a single query,

```
select p from Project p
left join fetch p.requester
left join fetch p.approver
```

Comment: I will go through your answer carefully and will try to grasp it and will certainly come back. Thanks a lot.

Comment: I have one question, in Project Entity can I do as `@ManyToOne @JoinColumn(name = "Requested_By")
    private Employee requester;` and `@ManyToOne @JoinColumn(name = "Approved_By")
    private Employee approver;`

Comment: Yes. If you don't specify a JoinColumn annotation, a default join column name will be assumed.

Comment: Initially I did not specify JoinColumn and upon execution I did get errors with invalid column names.

Comment: Of course: the actual column names in the database didn't match with the default column names assumed by Hibernate.

Comment: My second question is regarding the query, I can use `@NamedQueries` annotation and call the query name in DAO implemenation class in order to fetch `requestorName` and `approverName` from `Employee` Entity? Thanks

Comment: I have managed to get desired results, thanks a lot for your help and support, appreciated.

Comment: As it is relates to `ManyToOne` I would like to ask another question if you do not mind. While persisting record and if a foreign key does not exist in mapping table, what is the best approach to restrict an insert, update and delete? What is my limited understanding of this matter is `ALL` does insert and delete if foreign key doesn't exist. And what is the difference between `MERGE` and `ALL`?

Comment: Ask another, much more detailed question, with code examples. I can't understand what you're asking.

Comment: Right, I have posted another question here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17809249/usage-of-cascade-cascadetype-and-fetch-fetchtype